# UITextField bind

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, xib

I can't figure out why that code is not working for me.

ViewController.h

```
...
@property (nonatomic, copy) UITextField *textField;
...
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [self.textField addTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(textIsChanged:) 
                           forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

}

-(void)textIsChanged:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"Changed");
}
```

When I type something in the textField textIsChanged method is never invoked.

Comment: One solution would be to implement UITextViewDelegate protocol into your viewController (and make it a delegate of textField). But first you could just try putting -(void)textIsChanged:(id)sender; into viewController's interface (in .h file)

Comment: I think that the property should be `retain` not `copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `textField` as an `IBOutlet` like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

or, if you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

and bind it from the xib file in interface builder.

Comment: I did that already but I get -[UITextInputTraits addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68f5ac0

Comment: I'm no expert... but should you & he have that property as `retain` not `copy`?

Comment: @TomH - I didn't notice that. You should probably post that as an answer. It may solve OP's issue.

Comment: I posted a separate answer if you want to accept that, but I don't really mind, as long as other people seeing this get the right answer.